# Google Cloud DatastoreAdmin usage without using this API directly

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using two APIs on Google cloud: Cloud Vision API and Maps JavaScript API. However, in the Google console, I can also see the usage of Cloud Datastore API even though I'm not using this API. The traffic on this API is a little bit strange because someone/something is making a call every 2 hours and Google returns 404 each time for this call.

I was trying to check which credential is used to call this API but when I deselect *anything* in the "Credentials" dropdown the data disappears.

How can I debug who/what is making the calls to Cloud Datastore? My understanding is that I can't disable this API because Cloud vision depends on this API.

[image]

EDIT: Problem is solved: we found out that we have an automatic tool in the company that is scanning each google cloud project.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can [enable Audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/audit-logging#enabling_audit_logging) to check "Who did what, where, and when?" within your Google Cloud resources. You can look at [Service Name](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/audit-logging#service_name) field to find monitored **Resource type** for the resources you are looking for, which contains the target of the audited operation. For descriptive information, see [Monitored resource types](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types:%7E:text=instance%20is%20running.-,datastore_database,-Cloud%20Datastore%20Database).

**Note:** If you use the Google Cloud console to modify a metrics scope, then those operations aren't recorded in an audit log. The Google Cloud console doesn't invoke the metrics scopes API for those transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the info! We found out that it was some security scan that the security team was running for each google cloud credential created in our company...